# mod_rewrite newbie needs help with (simple?) rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I tried.  I failed.  Here's what I want to do:

Using firebug I saw that the GET string in the request header for my stylesheets and other content was being munged by the application (which I can't modify).  I think a simple rewrite rule might help but I can't get it to work.  Here's what I need:

---

input:  **/content/2010/08/forum/styles/xyz/theme/normal.css**

output: **/forum/styles/xyz/theme/normal.css**

---

input:  **/content/forum/styles/xyz/template/blah.js**

output  **/forum/styles/xyz/template/blah.js**

---

input:  **/content/my-own-page/forum/happy.htm**

output: **/forum/happy.htm**

---

So, whatever comes in IF it contains "forum/" then get rid of what precedes "forum/" and return everything from "forum/", foward.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should probably do the job.

```
RewriteRule ^.*/forum/(.*)$ /forum/$1
```